# I want to add 2 foreign keys in my main table from same child table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Here oldCityId is mapped to cityId and newCityId is also mapped to cityId
How I can do that using java or JPA or hibernate.
table address with fields

- oldCityId [FK]
- NewCityId [FK]
- street
  -buildingNo

table City with fields

- cityId [PK]
  -cityName

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? It should be pretty straightforward, just use two `@ManyToOne` associations to a `City` entity. You can customize join column names using `@JoinColumn(name = ...)`, if needed

Comment: I am getting compilation error when using @ManyToOne annotation Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.accenture.lta.dealer.entities.Address column: city_id(should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Comment: Did you use `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "oldCityId") private City oldCity` and `@ManyToOne @JoinColumn(name = "newCityId") private City newCity`?